# How do you upgrade the MYSQL version that Mamp Pro uses?

Tags: mysql, mac-osx, mamp

I'm currently using Mamp Pro for a local dev environment on Mac OSX Mountain Lion. Ideally I'd like to update the version of mysql.

**How do you upgrade the MYSQL version that Mamp Pro uses?**

Comment: If you have purchased MAMP PRO as a commercial product, you should probably contact them for support.   If you did manage to upgrade Mysql as separate component, then you will almost certainly break the integration.

Comment: Development tools (like the integrated MAMP, XAMPP, etc. stacks) are generally considered off-topic for Server Fault (we're more geared toward system administrators installing & managing the individual components).  You should really be asking the folks that produce them these sorts of questions, or you could try on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) (though I'm not sure what kind of reception you'd get over there - "How do I upgrade MySQL?" is not really their area either...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is "You don't" - MAMP Pro is an integrated development tool, and if you elect to use it you're essentially stuck with the versions it provides.

If you need something it doesn't provide you have to manually install, configure, and manage the components (OS X, Apache, MySQL, and PHP).